# Simple.Data.PostgreSql throwing 'NpgsqlTypes.BitString' not found

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

After installing `Npgsql` and `Simple.Data.PostgreSql` from NuGet, and then using the following code:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["runningJournal"].ConnectionString;
var db = Database.OpenConnection(connectionString);
var userId = db.user.Insert(userName: "foo").userId;
```

I get this exception:

```
System.TypeLoadExceptionCould not load type 'NpgsqlTypes.BitString'
    from assembly 'Npgsql, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7'.
at Simple.Data.PostgreSql.TypeMap..cctor()
```

I assume that this is an issue with `Simple.Data.PostgreSql` since accessing the database from `Npgsql` works just fine. Is this a bug, or is there some other dependency that I need to manually add? Perhaps something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Npgsql 2.x had an NpgsqlTypes.BitString type which was removed in 3.0, which uses .NET's built-in [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It would seem that the version of `Simple.Data.PostgreSql` which you're using is compiled against Npgsql 2.x, but somehow you're using Npgsql 3.0 in your project. Make sure you're using Npgsql 2.2.7 and not 3.0.x, and perhaps let the `Simple.Data.PostgreSql` project know to release a new version which works with Npgsql 3.0.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Shay! The combination of Npgsql 2.2.7, Simple.Data.Ado 0.19.0.0, and Simple.Data.PostgreSql 0.17.0.0 is what finally worked for me.